# Using PCB after short-circuit

Tags: pcb, short-circuit

[image: Picture of the PCB]

So today I opened up my Senseo because I wanted to attach an arduino with a Bluetooth module to the 3 buttons (for some coffee when my alarm goes off). I wanted to measure the voltage but after the most idiotic move I made I shorted out the circuit. Now except from the black stuff in the left bottom corner I can't really determine any damaged components (nothing blown, nothing molten, diodes still work).

Now my question is, is it wise to keep on using this PCB or how do I test if the PCB still works?

Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]

[image: PCB after cleanup]

I cleaned the PCB and it looks good to me. The leftover burnt places are contactpoints of 2 resistors which are still working.

Comment: Wow. It is literary fried. If you want to fry something else - keep using it..

Comment: Damn, well time to get a replacement :/

Comment: How does it look after you clean it (e.g. with isopropyl alchohol)? *What* did you short out?

Comment: Maybe a trace acted like a fuse and blew.  Try cleaning it with isopropyl alcohol then check continuity on the traces.  Hopefully this is only a 2-layer board.  If you find a trace that isn't continuous you can jumper it

Comment: I'll clean it in a moment, I shorted the L - wire, with the blue pump wire. Needlessly to say, it blew the fuse!

Comment: Doesn't necessarily look fatal- clean it up and lets have a look at it. Maybe it just needs the PCB bridged.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's my place to say this, but I think that you are treading a dangerous path.

This circuit is obviously AC-Mains powered and I don't see any form of isolation.  That isn't a problem for someone who has significant electronics experience but the fact that you can't deal with blown traces on a PCB suggests that you do **NOT** have the required experience to do this safely.

I'm not concerned about your ability to repair this unit.  What causes my concern is that you are connecting devices that eventually connect to other devices.

For example, do you know what will happen when you plug the USB connector from your Arduino into your computer while both the Arduino and the AC Mains are connected to this board.  Hint: it involves lots of smoke, sparks, maybe even flames.  It may also involve electric shock.

Comment: Well I'm obviously not going to connect my arduino to the AC power of this pcb. I was going for the easy solution of drilling a hole in the machine then adding a power cable for the arduino. And I planned on using relays to bypass buttons so to speak.